# Running module unit tests from CLI: "Class '..' could not be found"

Tags: 8, testing

I am trying to run module-provided <strike>PhpUnit</strike> tests from the CLI.

Following [these instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2116263), so my core/phpunit.xml should be correct now.

Using this command:

```
cd core
../vendor/bin/phpunit modules/system/src/Tests/Installer/InstallerTranslationTest.php
```

I get this output:

```
Class 'modules/system/src/Tests/Installer/InstallerTranslationTest' could not be found in '/****/core/modules/system/src/Tests/Installer/InstallerTranslationTest.php'.
```

Module-provided tests in e.g. `core/modules/system/tests/src/..`, are found, and work correctly with the phpunit command. But tests in `core/modules/system/src/Tests/..` do not seem to work, or be detected.

(I think I had this problem before, and someone told me what was missing. But I don't remember anything. Time to document this in this Q/A site.)

Comment: Maybe I need the `run-tests.sh` for those? If so, then this is not properly documented on https://www.drupal.org/node/2116263 ..

Comment: Ok I think I get it: Those tests are not really "PhpUnit tests". And this is why the phpunit command does not work here. There should be a link from that doc page to where the other kind of tests are explained.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the solution is

From Drupal root directory:

```
sudo -u www-data php core/scripts/run-tests.sh --url http://d8.localhost/ --class "Drupal\system\Tests\Installer\InstallerTranslationTest"
```

Assuming that your site is available under http://d8.localhost, and it is an installed site.

Maybe you want to use `--verbose` for more output.

Documentation on drupal.org: [Running Tests Through command-line](https://www.drupal.org/node/645286)